Bottleneck for the search of a graph of chromatic number 6
Since de Grey's discovery of a planar unit distance graph of chromatic number 5 having 1581 vertices, smaller ones have been found, the smallest with 509 vertices (per wikipedia).
Q1: is 509 indeed the current record?
Q2: what is the bottleneck to combine various copies of that graph to find a planar unit distance graph of chromatic number 6?
Q3: could AI help?

There's another condition on these graphs, isn't there? Something about all the vertices being points in the plane, and all the edges having length one? Otherwise, there's no challenge finding graphs with chromatic number as high as you want, with very few vertices.

This was implicit in the question, thanks to JoshuaZ for the clarifying edit.
